# Add a feature to alert everyone who commented

Tags: feature-request, comments

Is there any chance that we could add a feature where you could put, say, `@all-involved` in the comment so that it would alert everyone who commented on that answer/question.

There have been a few times where I have had a question that involves the current question enough that it didn't seem to warrant asking a totally new question. In that case if I wanted to ask everyone I would have to comment @soso COMMENT, then comment @soANDso COMMENT, etc.

I know that it auto-notifies the poster and that is useful, but sometimes I see questions with multiple users commenting and if I want to comment the same thing to the other users, it's a pain.

Comment: This has the potential for abuse in which people just go around to large comment threads pinging everyone just to annoy people.

Comment: No thanks. I don't always want to be notified just because someone decided to comment on a year old post that I forgot I once commented on.

Comment: @Servy That has the potential to make people avoid long comment threads, or flag them for removal. Everybody wins!  :)

Comment: @Servy good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If The Stack Exchange does what you propose and I add a comment to the oldest **nondeleted** post on SO: [While applying opacity to a form should we use a decimal or double value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4/561731), which is from more that **FIVE YEARS** ago many people will get upset.

There is no reason for this at all!

If you want to @comment more than one person, you ***need*** to make separate comments, otherwise many people could get pulled into a post that they may not have looked at for **years**

Comment: Ok, you're right. Just thought I'd ask. Ouch. -8 Post :P I went from 101 rep to 88.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Note that for feature requests on meta, votes mean something like 'I agree / disagree that this would be a valuable feature to add and worthy of the developer's time to implement'.